# Running Node-Red in a Docker Container on my Server - where store data files (csv)?

Tags: node.js, docker, node-red

I have a problem with my server - docker - node-red setup.
I started a container on my server with the following command:

```
docker run -d \ --name=node-red \ --restart=always \
-p 1880:1880 \ -u 1000:1000 \ 
-v /home/maximus/node-red:/data \ nodered/node-red-docker:latest
```

I can login to Node-Red using port 1886 and start creating flows.
Within one flow I want to use a .csv-file which is also stored on my server. (currently under `/home/maximus/node-red/`)

When I enter this path to the node properties (file in) in Node-red I get an error after injecting the flow.

Does anyone know where I have to store the cdv file to be able to use it in Node-red? I can imagine that I have to store it within the docker container but don't know where exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't connect to port 1886? In your docker command you have used port 1880. With -v command what you are doing is mounting the host’s /home/maximus/node-red directory as the user configuration directory inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to use the volume mount you already have.

Put the csv file into `/home/maximus/node-red` on the host and it will be available in the docker container in `/data`